# Area path error when Source and Target Area Paths are different while migrating Work Items from TFS to Azure through VSTS

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Below is the structure in source:
Drug Library Editor

Below is the structure in Target:
DaVinci\xx\yy\zz\Drug Library

Below is what I have for the query :

```
"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Specification' AND [System.AreaPath] Under 'DaVinci\\xx\\yy\\zz\\Drug Library' ",
```

Below is the error I get when I am executing the processor, it fails when running the query on the target system to find if the work item has already been migrated:

```
[07:52:38 DBG] WorkItemQuery: Query: SELECT [System.Id], [System.Tags] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'DaVinci' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Specification' AND [System.AreaPath] Under 'DaVinci\Infusion\Neo\Connectivity\Drug Library'  ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc
[07:52:38 DBG] WorkItemQuery: Paramiters: {"TeamProject": "DaVinci"}
[07:52:38 DBG] WorkItemQuery: TeamProject: DaVinci
[07:54:31 INF] Replay all revisions of 748 work items?
[07:54:31 INF] Found target project as Test_Connectivity
[07:54:31 INF] [FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget] is enabled. Searching for work items that have already been migrated to the target...
[07:54:31 DBG] FilterExistingWorkItems: START |
[07:54:31 DBG] FilterByTarget: Query Execute...
[07:54:31 DBG] WorkItemQuery: ===========GetWorkItems=============
[07:54:31 DBG] WorkItemQuery: TeamProjectCollection: https://dev.azure.com/BD-MMS-Connectivity/
[07:54:31 DBG] WorkItemQuery: Query: SELECT [System.Id], [Custom.TFSID] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'Test_Connectivity' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Specification' AND [System.AreaPath] Under 'DaVinci\Infusion\Neo\Connectivity\Drug Library'  ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc
[07:54:31 DBG] WorkItemQuery: Paramiters: {"TeamProject": "Test_Connectivity"}
[07:54:31 DBG] WorkItemQuery: TeamProject: Test_Connectivity
[07:54:31 ERR]  Error running query
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51011: The specified area path does not exist. The error is caused by «'DaVinci\Infusion\Neo\Connectivity\Drug Library'».
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Query(String wiql, IDictionary context)
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemsFromQuery(TfsWorkItemMigrationClient wiClient) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 40
[07:54:31 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51011: The specified area path does not exist. The error is caused by «'DaVinci\Infusion\Neo\Connectivity\Drug Library'».
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Query(String wiql, IDictionary context)
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemsFromQuery(TfsWorkItemMigrationClient wiClient) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 72
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItems() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 28
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.FilterExistingWorkItems(List`1 sourceWorkItems, TfsWiqlDefinition wiqlDefinition, TfsWorkItemMigrationClient sourceWorkItemMigrationClient) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 51
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 117
at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
[07:54:31 ERR] WorkItemMigration The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
[07:54:31 INF] Application is shutting down...
[07:54:31 DBG] Hosting stopping
[07:54:31 DBG] Exiting with return code: 0
``
Of course source Area Path does not exist in Target project. How to resolve this?
Is there a way for the query to use one Area Path when executing in source and another Area path in Target.
```

Comment: AFAIK, I am afraid there is no such way to to use one Area Path when executing in source and another Area path in Target for the query.

Comment: So I need to mimic the same Area path in my Target project?

Comment: @maryamghani, Have you add the field map when you migrate the workitems? https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Processors/WorkItemMigrationConfig.html. And if the target path `DaVinci\Infusion\Neo\Connectivity\Drug Library` exists in your target project? If not, try to create the area path.

Comment: @maryamghani, Is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The same query is run against both the Source and the Target. Therefor adding the NodePath to the query will result in an error if it does not also exist in the target (which it cant as the project name is in the path)

Use the NodePath filter argument instead.